# Identify admin/logout and more filters

Tags: filters, user-meta

I have several links I need to apply filters to them. Having hard time understanding from the documentation which are the correct filters I need to use.
I am not using the default theme.
This links are under the *META* box

1. Site Admin
2. Log out

Answer (score 0):

```
add_filter('login_url','....
add_filter('register','.....
```

`login_url` and `register` are the filter names that applies to the login link and to the admin link

Comment: Please explain **why** that could solve the problem.

Comment: I think from the question it is self explanatory, but, I added it.

Comment: When you explain a hook, tell the readers where the hook is called and what parameters can be used. An example callback would even be better.